# Proving a given statement in 3D trigonometry, but given NO side lengths

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

I've found $tan(\alpha)$, $tan(\beta)$ and $tan(\gamma)$ in terms of $h$ and the side lengths
but I'm having trouble proving what's required because these types of questions normally include numerical values for the side lengths
I think the key is using the bottom triangle - if I am correct then it is made up of two 45, 45, 90 triangles
So perhaps I use the ratios of such a triangle? 1, 1, √2

Comment: There is nothing in this that limits the distances of either $B$ or $C$ from $A$, so there is no reason to believe that the base triangle is isosceles. However, have you noticed that $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle APB$ are right triangles that both contain the same angle at $B$, and similarly $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle APC$ are right triangles that both contain the same angle at $C$?

Answer (score 4):

Let S b the area of triangle ABC, we have:

$2S=AC\times AB= AP\times BC$

$\frac{AC^2\cdot AB^2}{AP^2}=BC^2=AB^2+AC^2$

Dividing both sides by $AC^2\cdot AB^2$ we get:

$\frac 1{AP^2}=\frac 1{AB^2}+\frac 1{AC^2}$

Multiplying both sides by $h^2$ we get:

$\frac{h^2}{AP^2}=\frac{h^2}{AB^2}+\frac{h^2}{AC^2}$

Therefore:

$tan^2 \gamma=tan^2 \alpha + tan^2 \beta$